# VSTS How do I search All Fields?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to create a Query in VS Team Services > Work > Queries that searches all fields in Work Items that are indexed for full-text search.

To search for the text "confusing", I can create a query for 
Title contains confusing
OR Description contains confusing
OR Steps to Repro contains confusing
OR History contains confusing

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do so using Work Item Search. Just go to Work hub and type in the text "confusing" in the search box and hit Enter.